# MySQL: Why InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySql: MyISAM vs. Inno DB!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277440/mysql-myisam-vs-inno-db)

Hi,

I have a read through about MyISAM and InnoDB on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

> MyISAM manages nontransactional
>   tables. It provides high-speed storage
>   and retrieval, as well as fulltext
>   searching capabilities. MyISAM is
>   supported in all MySQL configurations,
>   and is the default storage engine
>   unless you have configured MySQL to
>   use a different one by default.

while,

> The InnoDB and BDB storage engines
>   provide transaction-safe tables. To
>   maintain data integrity, InnoDB also
>   supports FOREIGN KEY
>   referential-integrity constraints.

But I still don't understand - Why MyISAM or InnoDB.

InnoDB seems to be interesting but what kind of websites we should go for InnoDB? What is it actually for?  foreign key support - what is foreign key for?

I always have all my tables set with MyISAM for my website which have a CMS, Blog, Emailing, Newsletter sign up, searching purposes, etc.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I just read the answers from the other thread,

- MYISAM doesnt support any database
  transactions,
- INNODB will provide transactions
- MYISAM provides a table level
  locking,
- INNODB provides a row level locking

But I still don't get it -

database transactions - what does it mean? when do we actually use them?

a table level locking - what is it?

a row level locking - again, what is it? what is it for?

I am not asking about the difference between InnoDB and MYISAM - I wonder what kind of websites we should go for InnoDB? transaction websites? then what is a transaction website??

thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql: MyISAM vs. Inno DB!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277440/mysql-myisam-vs-inno-db) and a few others

Comment: To put it real short: curently the only advantage of MyISAM over InnoDB is the full-text seearch capability. If you need this, and don't have the ability to install an external full-text search engine, go with MyISAM. Otherwise use InnoDB and enjoy tables that do not crash.

Comment: @Mchl: thanks but I am sorry as I still have to ask - what is full-text search capability? what is it for?

Comment: innodb clustered indexes - read for speed !!!

Comment: @lauthiamkok: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search