# Syntax of queries on MYISAM vs that on InnoDB

Tags: mysql

I want to know if the syntax of the select query is different for MyISAM and InnoDB.
Let us suppose we have run a query on MyISAM and got a ResultSet,call it : A
Now we run the same query on InnoDB and get a ResultSet,call it B.
Will A and B have any difference or will A be equal to B.

Please reply as i need

Comment: For more info on the differences between the two see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277440/mysql-myisam-vs-inno-db

Answer (score 1):

The two storage engines support the same SQL syntax.

However, there are certain features that are supported in one storage engine but not the other. For example, `FULLTEXT` indexes that are supported in MyISAM but not InnoDB.

As for the result sets returned by MyISAM vs. InnoDB, they should return the same rows, but the rows may not be in the same order if you don't include a deterministic `ORDER BY` clause. For example, if you do not include an `ORDER BY` clause, or you `ORDER BY` a non-unique set of columns, then to some extent the rows will be sorted arbitrarily, which means the order could be different for different storage engines.