# Mysql Replication Delay issues

Tags: mysql, replication

We have configured one master and 5 slaves in mysql, but fifth slave always taking a delay more than half hour and same time fifth slave server always we are hitting the select queries through the application. So i referred more website for fixing this issues, but everyone was saying we cant improve or reduce the delay without reducing the select query.

So please share your input and how to solve the delay issues.

Regards,
Kumaran

Comment: is your BB schema optimized? is someone/process/code query that server using non-index where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the load on the server, the select queries are possibly causing table locks if your tables are `MyISAM`. If there are a lot of queries causing table locks then the replication will become delayed.

I would suggest changing your tables to `InnoDB` if you can to see if that helps as it reduces the chance of table locks ... among numerous other differences.

Keep in mind those differences between the tables types just in case it impacts your database in other ways - see my answer and others in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277440/mysql-myisam-vs-inno-db) for a brief summary.