# MySql misses short words in full text search query

Tags: mysql

I have table with a column 'on_phonetic' where phonetic keys for geographical coordinates stored.
Value examples are: 'KF' (for Kiev), 'ASKRK, 'KNX SSP',  etc

There is a fulltext index placed on this column.
Query which I am launching:

```
SELECT * FROM osm_nodes 
WHERE MATCH(`on_phonetic`) AGAINST ('LSF');
```

it works ok for values with length greater than 2.
but fails for values with length <= 2
so, this one will return nothing

```
SELECT * FROM osm_nodes 
WHERE MATCH(`on_phonetic`) AGAINST ('KF');
```

however this query (not full-text) below returns tree records

```
SELECT * FROM osm_nodes 
WHERE on_phonetic = 'KF';
```

I made following updates in my.ini - file

```
ft_min_word_len=2
ft_stopword_file = ""
```

restarted server (ensured that my changes appeared in 'variables' section), rebuild indexes, even recreated table - nothing help.
Any ideas ?

MySql version is 5.6.23-log, OS is Win7, x86_64

Thanks.

Comment: with only 2 chars of fulltext indexing, you may be running into many more things showing up as "noise" words due to appearing in 50%+ of results. Anything mysql considers noise wouldn't get returned as a result.

Comment: Marc B, is there any possibility to 'turn off' this 'node' feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default db engine (i think you have InnoDB) doesn't  support full text search  so you need to use MyISAM db engine.

[When to use MyISAM and InnoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678406/when-to-use-myisam-and-innodb)

Comment: btw, collation can be root of such problems

Comment: innodb has supported fulltext since 5.6.4 or somethign like that.

Answer (score 0):

Ha-ha, did not ever imagine that mysql full text works only with MyISAM engine.

Changing table type from InnoDB to myISAM resolved this issue