# How to speed up a search on the mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
 `IDClient` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `Phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 `passw` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `ip` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'IP адрес'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY (Phone)
 PARTITIONS 10 */;
ALTER TABLE `users`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Phone`),
 ADD KEY `IDClient` (`IDClient`),
 ADD KEY `ip` (`ip`);
```

It about 3 million records. When the site is a little loaded, sql request

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone='9123456789' LIMIT 1
```

takes about 0.03 seconds, but when the site more loaded this time can reach up to 5 seconds.
Who in the subject, can have any advice? Even 0.03 seconds, i think, much, for such a trivial request.

```
explain SELECT * FROM `users` where Phone="9123456789" limit 1

id  select_type table   type  possible_keys key     key_len ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE      users   const PRIMARY       PRIMARY 47      const   1       NULL
```

Maybe it helps the real partition table on 2,5,10 ... tables?
Thank you!

Comment: have you indexed the column phone??

Comment: Index is the ideal way to achieve speed

Comment: It is PRIMARY field index.

Comment: Do you have hyphens in the phone number field. Else consider changing it to integer rather than VARCHAR. INT fields are retrieved faster compared to VARCHAR fields.

Comment: if phone is primary key there is no need for LIMIT 1. Try partioning in MySQL

Comment: I use partioning( phone is login, there can be anything not required numbers

Comment: @PK20: And then the phone number `0555123456` comes along, and it's different from `555123456`. Now what? Or `+421900123456789`, which is not the same thing as `421900123456789`.

Answer (score 2):

Add index to the column used in where clause , it will surely enhance processing speed.

Comment: I have index. It is PRIMARY filed

Comment: You can try by adding index in primary key and the other way is create a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set at least one unique field otherwise all the field combined will be treated as key and this makes it much slower.

Comment: Primary field  is a UNIQUE field, isn't it?

Comment: It should be ! But it is possible to set index which isn't unique

Answer (score 0):

What Engine are you using? MyIsam is more fast for read operations and fulltext search. See this discussion. [When to use MyIsam and Innodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15678406/when-to-use-myisam-and-innodb)

**EDIT: I noticed that you specified the engine on the create table query. So you should consider using MyIsam engine instead of innodb.**