Insert/Update with NULL values in Oracle's JDBC causes performance issue
We have a Spring application connecting to Oracle via SpringJDBC (jdbcTemplate),
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
    <version>23.3.0.23.09</version>
</dependency>

In our DAO class we have an INSERT executed with jdbcTemplate.update():
String sql = """
                INSERT INTO 
                    MY_TABLE (
                        COL1,
                        COL2,
                        COL3)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
            """;
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, param1, param2, param3/* may be NULL*/);

The 3rd param may be a NULL value getting inserted. When it's not NULL, performance is fast, no issues. But when it happens to be NULL, it takes ~2 min on the first such insert, and it's still pretty slow (about 10-30 sec.) on all subsequent such Inserts.
This is not a DB problem: I verified in the DB (SqlDeveloper) that all INSERTs both with and without NULLs in this column are equally fast directly in the DB, so we can rule out the DB.
Since Oracle treats empty strings as NULLs, we found a good solution: just pass in an empty string for a NULL:
(param3 == null ? "" : param3)
and this fixes the performance issue, and NULL gets inserted. But is this NULL issue a known problem with Oracle's JDBC driver? I don't know if this will always work, like if the NULL/empty equivalence can be turned off in the DB. Are there other workarounds?

I am interested to see where the delay is originating from. You may want to consider profiling your program.

It is hard to see why it could be a JDBC driver problem.  What happens when you perform the same SQL insert on the same table using an SQL tool?

I updated my OP to indicate this is not a DB problem, because direct DB Inserts both with and without NULLs in SqlDeveloper are equally fast. So it must be a JDBC issue.

@StephenC See my answer. Equally fast in the DB (SqlDeveloper), no issues.

If COL3 is nullable and of a specific type, you could try casting the NULL to that type explicitly in your SQL: VALUES (?, ?, CAST(? AS VARCHAR2)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942063 - looks similar

You can't rule out the database just because you can do an insert through SQL Developer. If Spring is binding those values using proper bind variables, that's not the same as providing literals. There could be a problem, for example, in parse. You won't know for sure until you examine the wait interface (or ASH data) to see what, if anything, your session is doing during those long inserts. If you find nothing, then it's likely a client issue. But there is a chance you'll find some sort of concurrency mechanism, or a trigger that acts conditionally based on client, etc.

Under normal conditions, however, it would be very unusual to find a noticeable performance distinction between providing a NULL vs. a non-null value on an insert. Something on the client side is most likely, especially if '' works.

I would also try executing the same SQL with a regular PreparedStatement instead of going through Spring. If it performs better that way, then your issue is Spring, not the Oracle driver.

Perhaps the driver uses some kind of getObject / instance thing and for nulls it can't figure it out which takes a slower code path. oracle jdbc drivers is one of the worst on the market, so nothing surprises me. Also, it's closed source which is another big issue i have with it. Good luck reporting issues with the driver as well. Could be the issue with spring too, but then non-oracle code would have same issue too

@siggemannen Yeah I'm just surprised it's not a more widely discussed issue. My lead knew that Oracle JDBC has these kinds of problems, but I didn't.
